# Validation rule "between" for array of checkboxes always valid

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

If have a few questions displaying choice ids with ranking (First checkbox selected is first choice, etc). Here's a simplified `var_dump($_POST)` that was sent through the form:

```
Array
(
    [_token] => 6vPgIM1MX7MJ0DzMX2OFjCdPEBBel5mRJ6RzrEjR
    [11] => Array // Means question id 11
        (
            [42] => 2 // Means choice id 42 was chosen second
            [43] => 1 // Means choice id 43 was chosen first
            [44] => 3 // Means choice id 44 was chosen third
        )

    [12] => 

    [13] => Array
        (
            [4] => 1
        )

    [btn-validate] => CONTINUE
)
```

Then my `var_dump($validationRules)` is as follow:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => between:0,2
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => between:1,3
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => between:0,1
        )
)
```

And finally `var_dump($validationMessages)` (however not so much important here):

```
Array
(
    [11.between] => You should select between 0 and 2 choices
    [12.between] => You should select between 1 and 3 choices
    [13.between] => You should select between 0 and 1 choices
)
```

This is all wrapped up like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validationRules, $validationMessages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    var_dump($validator->errors());
    exit('fail'); // Never ends up here
}
exit('all good'); // Always ends up here
```

How to make the `between:x,y` validation rule work with an array of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

All my rules were ok, the problem is that Laravel's validation system doesn't support integer as `$_POST` keys

Laravel issue:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29116

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood how the between rule works for arrays.

From the [between rule docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-size):

> (...) Strings, numerics, arrays, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size rule.

From the [size rule docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-size):

> (...) For an array, size corresponds to the count of the array. (...)

Meaning the validation rules you specify mean the count of each of the array values is evaluated. In each case those are evaluated to true since the count is 1 in each of your cases.

Comment: I'm inclined to disagree haha ;) I really think "between" with an array is supposed to check the array size, not if every single item is between X and Y

Answer (score 0):

consider this as your check box
//blade file

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="likes_turtles" class="col-md-3 control-label">Likes Turtles</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="likes_turtles[]" value="Yes"> Yes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="likes_turtles[]" value="No"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="likes_turtles[]" value="Maybe so"> Maybe so
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you have validate in controller like bellow code

```
[
    "likes_turtles" => "required", 
    "likes_turtles.*" => "in:Yes,No,Maybe so"
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, don't think it's related.. but thanks but answering still